# ng-change not working after first upload

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change, input-type-file

http://embed.plnkr.co/keaGc3Y4Pmgfs04HJgnC/

Here is the link of my code.I am trying to validate my upload by disabling the load data button when the file is empty.
It is working for the first time,but when the next time I upload the file,ng-change is not working and the button is still showing disabled although I have uploaded the next file.
I am a beginner in AngularJS,so i might be doing some basic mistake.please help.

Comment: Do you always try with the same file? Because for me, it is working fine. Note that ng-change will not fire if you try to upload the same file again. (because there is no change)

Comment: ya...i am trying to upload the same file,is there any  workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to upload the same file again, the `onChange` event will not fire, because it is the same file. To resolve this issue, you need to unset the input field after you uploaded the file. Unfortunately, you have to use jQuery (or get the element wit vanilla js) for this. So, in your `onFileLoad` function you could do something like this:

```
angular.element("input[type='file']").val(null); // Unset Input
$scope.filename = undefined; // Unset $scope property
```

Note that this is not the "angular" way of doing this. It would be better to move this into a directive, cause you should not manipulate the DOM within a Controller.

**Update**:
As said before, you need to include jQuery for this to work. Angular's jqLite does not support selecting DOM elements by its `type`. So, either you include jQuery (needs to be loaded before angular!) or you modify the code so you can use vanilla JS or jqlite.

Answer (score -1):

```
Please change, initially

vm.foo = 'Monthly'

<input type="radio" name="{{item.deviceId}}" ng-model="renew.foo" ng-value="'Monthly'" ng-click="renew.updatePref(item, 'Monthly')">Monthly
<input type="radio"  name="{{item.deviceId}}" ng-model="renew.bar" ng-value="'Yearly'" ng-click="renew.updatePref(item, 'Yearly')">Yearly
you have use ng-change, change event never happen as value for these input remains always same. use,

var vm = this;
you are also using ng-value="Monthly", Monthly is variable (undefiend) for ng-value. either use value="Monthly" or ng-value="'Monthly'".
```

Comment: please elaborate(I think this solution is not relevant for my question)